# Web Service Client Error in Java

Tags: java, web-services, cisco-axl

I don't know this is the right platform to ask this question or not, but as this question is related to programming, so that's why i am going to ask this question that might be i get some clue about the problem. 
Actually i work in Cisco CVP environment, I have to communicate with the GRC web service, i have made web service client (Web service client from Wsdl in netbeans )  for the webservice. 
Now i have got a jar file, i have run this jar application on the required production machine, i got correct result in the console, which mean client is working fine. 
Now after that i have included this jar in my VXML Cisco IVR project but when i call this jar file inside of that project , on the same machine i am getting this error.

```
10.83.10.21.1424071445429.22.CF_CAM999,02/16/2015 07:24:05.476,A custom element encountered an exception. The error was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:604)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:308)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
    at ma.iam.wsgold.ws.impl.FidelioWebServiceImplService.getFidelioWebServiceImplPort(FidelioWebServiceImplService.java:72)
    at goldwsclient.GoldWsClient.getInfoFidelioByND(GoldWsClient.java:40)
    at goldwsclient.Converter.<init>(Converter.java:20)
    at com.ef.client.iam.cbrupgrade.service_999.CheckGold999.doAction(CheckGold999.java:20)
    at com.audium.server.voiceElement.ActionElementBase.service(ActionElementBase.java:387)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToAction(Controller.java:2911)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2643)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2468)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2694)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2468)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2694)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2468)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2694)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2468)
    at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:696)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can i get any help or clue that how can i troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Comment: Why Negative mark , May i ask?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you tried to use a variable that was set to be private/protected in another class/package, but I could only know such thing for sure when some source code would be available...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue i have used the following way to resolve it
Actually this error is occurring due to the jar conflict in the CVP to resolve it i have gone to Tomcat following path and remove one jar "jaxws-rt" from the tomcat lib.
CVP\VXMLServer\Tomcat\webapps\CVP\WEB-INF\lib
After removing this jar my issue resolved.